# ¿cómo generar un pie y encabezado con DOMPDF?

Tags: php, html, css, php5, dompdf

Estoy tratando de generar un PDF con DOMPDF, lo que quiero es poder repetir el encabezado y el pie en varias páginas.
Solo lo pone en la primera página, pero en la segunda, solo pone el margen y no pone los estilos no el contenido.
He visto ejemplos, pero la mayoría es utilizando las funciones propias de DOMPDF, lo que he intentado es solo con HTML y CSS y colocando `style="page-break-before: always;"` para hacer los datos de página.

El siguiente código es el que he probado, pero solo coloca el encabezado y el píe de la primera página.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
   <style type="text/css">
   @page {
   margin: 160px 50px;
   }
   .cabezaR { position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
   top: -160px;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100px;
   background-color: #ddd;
   text-align: center;
   }
   .cabezaR h1{
   margin: 10px 0;
   }
   .cabezaR h2{
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
   }
   .pieR {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0px;
   bottom: -50px;
   right: 0px;
   height: 40px;
   border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
   }
   .pieR .page:after {
   content: counter(page);
   }
   .pieR table {
   width: 100%;
   }
   .pieR p {
   text-align: right;
   }
   .pieR .izq {
   text-align: left;
   }
  </style>
   <div class="cabezaR">
     <h1>Cabecera de mi documento</h1>
     <h2>contenido</h2>
   </div>
   <div class="pieR">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
              <p class="izq">
                mas contenido
              </p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <p class="page">
              Página
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
    <div id="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit...
      </p>
      <p>
      Vestibulum pharetra fermentum fringilla...
      </p>
      <p style="page-break-before: always;">
      Podemos romper la página en cualquier momento...</p>
      </p>
      <p>
      Praesent pharetra enim sit amet...
      </p>
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: lo pudistes solucionar¿